# Inserting only new records from one db server to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We have a phone system database on one server but we want an updated clone on our production server.

I've dumped the original and imported it to our local production server, which is great, but now I have to go about keeping it updated with any daily changes on the other server.

I'm trying to create a php script that will simply check each table on the other server and then insert any new records in each table into the cloned table on our production database.

Below is a test select/insert block. The select query works with no errors but my insert returns an error as I expected, because I believe I'm using `NOT EXISTS` incorrectly. I don't know if that's even the best  route to take.

The session table has about 35 columns so I'm looking for the best way to go about this without having to declare every column if possible. The only thing I though of is the `SESSION.SESSIONID` field which is the primary key. So my logic below was, `if the sessionid from the phone server doesn't exist yet in the prod server, insert the whole record`.

So obviously my syntax is wrong on the insert, just looking for some guidance on how to insert all new records from server1.session to server2.session when this script is run every 15 minutes.

```
//Defining credentials
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$servername2 = "";
$username2 = "";
$password2 = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// Check connection2
if ($conn2->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";


//Query to select * from Session table on server 1
$query1 = "select * from cdrdb.session";
$results = mysqli_query($conn1, $query1);

foreach ($results as $r => $result) {

}

$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "insert into ambition.session a where not 
exists(a.SESSIONID)");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most appropriate way would have to be with a "log" table containing IDs.

However, I imagine the rows IDs are primary keys.

So, you want to do a script where you :

1. Get all rows from the source table
2. Loop on it with a foreach
3. Switch database
4. Do a SQL check on the destination database : `SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE id = $id`
5. If you have results (check with numRows()), don't do anything.
6. If you don't, then insert in the destination table with the value from foreach

Edit : 
Basically, you should do something like this :

```
$source_db = array(
    'host' => 'source_host',
    'name' => 'source_name',
    'user' => 'source_user',
    'pass' => 'source_pass'
);

$dest_db = array(
    'host' => 'dest_host',
    'name' => 'dest_name',
    'user' => 'dest_user',
    'pass' => 'dest_pass'
);

$source_conn = new mysqli($source_db['host'], $source_db['user'], $source_db['pass'], $source_db['name']);
$dest_conn = new mysqli($dest_db['host'], $dest_db['user'], $dest_db['pass'], $dest_db['name']);

// Get all rows from source database
$source_data = $source_conn->query("SELECT * FROM source_table");

// Loop on the results
while($source_item = $source_data->fetch_assoc()) {

    // Check if row exists in dest database
    $row_exists = $dest_conn->query("SELECT id FROM dest_table WHERE id = '".$source_item['id']."' ");

    // If the query returns FALSE, the row does not exist
    if(!$row_exists) {

        // Insert the new row in dest database
        $dest_conn->query("INSERT INTO dest_table (id, name) VALUES ('".$source['id']."', '".$source['name']."' ");
    }

}
```

Comment: So I want to insert into ambition.session, meaning I would say ```SELECT sessionid FROM ambition.session WHERE sessionid = $id``` assuming i use ```$id``` as the variable in a foreach loop? My select query is already working so can I build it from that?

Comment: Yes. Your foreach loop will look like this :
foreach($items AS $k => $item) 
So the columns defined in your SQL SELECT will be in the $item array.
Your var $id will be : $item['sessionid']

Comment: I think this makes sense, I'm just not an expert at this so I'm going to play with it and see what I can create. Then if I have any issues I may bring it back here and see what might be changed. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated with current code, can you tell me if I'm on the right track? I'm still a bit lost on how to apply the results to the insert

Comment: Yes you're on the right track. You just need mysqli_select_db() after connection errors (source database) and another in the foreach loop with the destination database.

Comment: Im not sure i understand. I've never really formed a loop like this doing an insert if not exists on MySQL so I don't totally understand the format and syntax fully. Is there any way you can give me a pseudo code example?

Comment: I think that makes sense now. So if my original select is grabbing all 35 columns, would I have to declare all 35 columns in that insert? Or is there a way to insert the whole array/record based on the missing records

Comment: Your script is simple, don't waste your time doing a routine just because you are lazy to write 35 field names ;)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Oh definitely, I don't mind doing it, I just want to follow best practices. So if I had ```INSERT into ambition.session (SESSIONID, ts, calledparty,callingparty, etc)``` then I would have ```VALUES('".$source['SESSIONID']."', '".$source['ts'].",' '".$source['calledparty']."', '".$source['callingparty']."  etc.' )```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL the EXISTS clause (?) is a subquery and looks like this (...WHERE EXISTS(SELECT ... FROM table ...))
Also you didn't state in the insert statement what to insert.
So i would do something like this:

```
INSERT ambition.session a (col_a, col_b, ...) SELECT col_a, col_b, ... FROM cdrdb.session c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ambition.session a2 WHERE a2.SESSIONID = c.SESSIONID);
```

Or you can do an INSERT IGNORE ... which will ignore the insertion if it would result in duplicate key and omit the whole WHERE clause, but i don't know if this would bring any performance issue.

I read that you may leave out the column names, but i don't know if it is true. Then:

```
INSERT ambition.session a SELECT * FROM cdrdb.session c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ambition.session a2 WHERE a2.SESSIONID = c.SESSIONID);
```

Comment: I think I understand here, but just to clarify: If it has to read through thousands of records on server 1, but say only 300 are new (meaning I only need to insert 300 into my table on server 2) then I could use either of those options and it should insert only those new 300 rows? And I'm leaning toward your 2nd one becuase there are so many columns that I'd have to declare otherwise. I want to select/insert every field per record, but only if it doesn't exist

Comment: If the columns of the two tables (in the two databases) are the same and the existing unique id's are the same, they should work. Again, i don't know if leaving out the column names can work, i've never tried it.